# Selenium: Check if a WebElement has the focus

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was expecting something like WebElement.isfocus(),... something really simple, but the only approach I found is using the

```
:focus
```

pseudo class.

Is this really such an uncommon task as for not find tons of information?

I'm aware of [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400708/selenium-ide-how-to-check-if-an-element-has-a-focus), but it's been almost two years from then. Nothing new in more recent versions?

Would you know some workaround?

Comment: What's the use of it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to know if the focus is set to a given TextBox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if an element is focused using Selenium Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552169/test-if-an-element-is-focused-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is another topic that covers this issue: [Test if an element is focused using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552169/test-if-an-element-is-focused-using-selenium-webdriver)

Basically the code will be

```
element.equals(driver.switchTo().activeElement());
```

Answer (score 8):

for python developers:

```
def is_element_focus(id):
    return self.driver.find_element_by_id(id) == self.driver.switch_to.active_element
```