# Active Element doesn't compare to wanted WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, compare, element

I have this selenium test, written in Java, that tests for the active element on the page to compare to a declared `WebElement` on the page. I've looked all over the internet for an answer, but haven't been successful. This is what I had, but it fails as it doesn't compare the active element and the `WebElement` that I want.

```
public class OWBLocatorInquiryPage extends BasePage {
  @FindBy(id = "orderNo")   
  private WebElement focusOnOrderNumberWE; 

  private String locatorInquiryPageString = "locatorInquiry.owb";

  public OWBLocatorInquiryPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
  }

  public boolean isFocusedOnOrderNumber() {
    WebElement focusElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
    return (focusElement == focusOnOrderNumberWE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell via looking around, == is an address comparison.
Some discussion here: [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

I would recommend trying

```
return (focusElement.equals(focusOnOrderNumberWE));
```

based on discussion here: [Selenium: Check if a WebElement has the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025282/selenium-check-if-a-webelement-has-the-focus)